# Replacing values in a sting with an array of other values

Tags: php, regex

I wish to replace all `src` attributes of `img` tags in a string.

My string:

```
$string = "some text with <img src='/uploads/images/5d0554.jpeg'> and 
<img src='/uploads/images/507a.jpeg'> or <img src='/uploads/images/0a74.jpeg'> in it.";
```

should become:

```
$string = "some text with <img src='some/value/one.jpeg'> and 
<img src='alue/SomethingElse.png'> or <img src='Value3'> in it.";
```

What I tried to do:

```
$regex = '/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$srcMatches = $matches[1];

$replacementValues = ["some/value/one.jpeg", "value/SomethingElse.png", "Value3"];

preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) use (&$replacementValues) {
    return array_shift($replacementValues);
}, $string);
```

This gives me

```
some long text with some/value/one.jpeg'> and 
value/SomethingElse.png'> or Value3'> in it.
```

I also tried with `preg_replace`, but that gave me issues because of all the `/`'s  in the values to be replaced.

Comment: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1839439)

Comment: There is  also an option to use domdocument and load the string as html with for example a wrapper to access it by id. Then you can replace the image names and get back the html. See https://3v4l.org/NL950

Answer (score 0):

This expression would likely do the replacements using 6 capturing groups:

```
$re = '/([\s\S]*?)(src=[\'"])\/uploads\/images\/.+?(\..+?)([\'"]>[\s\S]*?src=[\'"])\/uploads\/images\/.+?\..+?([\'"]>[\s\S]*?src=[\'"])\/uploads\/images\/.+?\..+?([\'"]>[\s\S]*)/m';
$str = 'some text with <img src=\'/uploads/images/5d0554.jpeg\'> and 
<img src=\'/uploads/images/507a.jpeg\'> or <img src=\'/uploads/images/0a74.jpeg\'> in it.';
$subst = '$1$2some/value/one$3$4alue/SomethingElse\\.png$5Value3$6';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
some text with <img src='some/value/one.jpeg'> and 
<img src='alue/SomethingElse.png'> or <img src='Value3'> in it.
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tlonvN/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is not reusable enough. My regex should capture all kinds of urls within `scr="..."`, and also the replacement values can be very different.

Comment: Because I only want to target the `src` attributes of `img` elements. And no, they can be very different unfortunately.